# Delete a list of columns in a 2d array using java script

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to delete some columns in a 2d array. The list is named as hiddenCols

```js
var array = [
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["a", "b", "c"]
]

hiddenCols = [3, 1] // these are pos and not indexes
for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < hiddenCols.length; i++) {

    array[j].splice(hiddenCols[i], hiddenCols[i])
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

The expected result is var array = [["b"],["b"],["b"]];

Comment: `for (var j = 0; i < array.length; i++) {` the variable `j` is declared as a loop variable but `i` is used in the check for termination.

Comment: The expected result is var array = [["b"],["b"],["b"]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do with `Arrya#reduce`

```js
const arr = [["a", "b", "c"],["a", "b", "c"],["a", "b", "c"]];
const hiddenCols = [3, 1];

let result = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  let res = item.filter((_, ind) => hiddenCols.indexOf(ind + 1) == -1);
  acc.push(res)
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

Comment: No need for `reduce()` since you're returning an array of the same length simply use `map()`

Comment: @pilchard yes.. but someone already posted. And this also one of the method right then why down-voted

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.map()` to iterate the rows, and filter the items by checking that the position is not included in `hiddenCol`:

```js
const arr = [["a", "b", "c"],["a", "b", "c"],["a", "b", "c"]]

const hiddenCols = [3, 1]
const result = arr.map(item =>
  item.filter((_, ind) => !hiddenCols.includes(ind + 1))
)

console.log(result)
```